# Windows 7 XP Mode disable time sync

Tags: windows-7, sync, microsoft-virtual-pc, time, windows-xp-mode

So I've tried the trick from Virtual PC 2007, adding the following section to the vmc configuration file:

```
<components>
    <host_time_sync>
        <enabled type="boolean">false</enabled>
    </host_time_sync>
</components>
```

Later someone suggested VPC doesn't want the components level so added this instead:

```
<host_time_sync>
    <enabled type="boolean">false</enabled>
    <frequency type="integer">15</frequency>
    <threshold type="integer">10</threshold>
</host_time_sync>
```

When I start up XP Mode (Microsoft Virtual PC) it completely ignores any of these two configuration changes and if I change the clock it's instantly reset to the host time again. I've also obviously disabled the Windows Time service but as it's not joined to a domain or set up with a source it shouldn't be involved anyway.

I need to test an application over a few midnight passes and thought the XP Mode machine would be perfect, so I didn't have to mess with my workstation clock... is there any way to get the VPC guest to not sync time with the host? This is easy in Hyper-V ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VBScript posted by Sandy Wadhwa on at the following link worked for me:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprovirt/thread/aca326fd-8e37-49f3-8b90-4eda93a11cd6#5bd85a23-5e88-4a59-97d2-fb67422646fe

Answer (score 1):

You just need to shut down instead of hybernate before your changes to the vmc file take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to add your instructions inside a `<components>` tag like it is shown on the [Virtual PC Guy's page](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2007/11/28/disabling-time-synchronization-under-virtual-pc-2007.aspx)?

Comment: Yes I tried that first, didn't work - then in some MSDN forum thread someone suggested removing the components part for VPC. Which did no difference.